# How does the imgui window start modelessly without affecting the normal operation of the parent window

Tags: user-interface, plugins, mfc, window, imgui

I'm working on a project recently. It turned out to be done with MFC. The window is displayed in a non-modal form. It will interact with the parent window normally. It's similar to a game plug-in. MFC works normally , but I learned it recently. imgui, I found that this library is particularly beautiful and easy to learn, and I am ready to change hands, but I have encountered a lot of trouble, because after imgui is started, it has been in the while loop, which caused my parent window to not operate normally, and the new thread method was used. It is a bit incompatible with my software. I abandon this solution. Do you have any new solutions? Some people say that writing the code into the WM_PAINT message event does not seem to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPqoh.png)

Comment: Switching UI frameworks doesn't remove the requirement to understand the underlying system. Indeed, using *any* framework just doubled the amount of things you have to learn. You need a solid foundation of how Windows' native windowing system works. Petzold's [Programming Windows](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) teaches you that. There are no shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will learn this convenient knowledge， In fact, I just need to solve this trouble and I will become very happy.  -.- !